# Accessing data from an array of a a type class array Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuCOr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDdbU.png)

I have declared a array of the type subject [] and get information from an api and pushed the subjects into the Arr array.
My console looks like the attached images.
I want to access the subjects using angular and when i try using this.subject[0] it returns undefined.

so its not an array within an array i need to some help accessing that data, ill be using it to dynamically create labels on a graph from chart js.

```
Arr: Subject [] = new Array();
 
loadSubjects() {
  this.ss.getSubjects().subscribe(( subject: Subject[]) => {
    this.subject = subject;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.subject.length; i++) {
        this.subjArray.push(this.subject[i]['name']);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using map function

[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/851AVWvuKuOnWDuJ?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1) for the Plunker Solution

Also adding the piece of code below:

```
this.list1 = [
  {Name: "abc", Capacity: "150", Series: "20", Make: "150", Model: "150", TowerHeight: "151"},
  {Name: "def", Capacity: "250", Series: "250", Make: "250", Model: "252", TowerHeight: "250"},
  {Name: "ghi", Capacity: "151", Series: "21", Make: "151", Model: "151", TowerHeight: "152"}
  ];


this.list2 = this.list1.map(item => { return item.Name});
```

In your case I think it will be like

```
this.subjArray = this.subject.map(item => { return item.name});
```

### OUTPUT

**List 1:**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "Capacity": "150",
        "Series": "20",
        "Make": "150",
        "Model": "150",
        "TowerHeight": "151"
    },
    {
        "Name": "def",
        "Capacity": "250",
        "Series": "250",
        "Make": "250",
        "Model": "252",
        "TowerHeight": "250"
    },
    {
        "Name": "ghi",
        "Capacity": "151",
        "Series": "21",
        "Make": "151",
        "Model": "151",
        "TowerHeight": "152"
    }
]
```

**List 2:**

```
[ "abc", "def", "ghi" ]
```

This can be done with for loop as well. But map will be simpler in angular for chart data scenarios where we need to get single property value in an array